# I keep getting bcp error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?  I am trying to queryout to a flat file based on the data I manipulated.  I keep getting an error with the code below.
Appreciate all your help!

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?  I am trying to queryout to a flat file based on the data I manipulated.  I keep getting an error with the code below.
Appreciate all your help!

```
   declare variables....

    select @effDate = effective_date from c_flt_src 

    if convert(varchar(10), @effDate, 112) = convert (varchar(10), GETDATE(),112)
        set @sqleffdate = convert(varchar(10), @effDate, 112)
        begin
            select @all = store from c_flt_src where store = 'ALL'

                if @@ROWCOUNT = 1 and @all = 'ALL'
                    select @action = action from c_flt_src 
                        if @action = 'INCREASE' or @action = 'DECREASE'
                            set @actiontyp = 'UPDATE_STORE'
                        else if @action = 'REPLACE'
                            set @actiontyp = 'RESET_STORE'


                    select @a = a_amt from c_flt_src 
                    select @b = b_amt from c_flt_src 

                    begin
                        declare @c as cursor
                        set @c = CURSOR fast_forward for select distinct top 3 store from store_loc where store <> 0 order by store 
                            open @c
                                fetch next from @c into @store
                                    while @@FETCH_STATUS  = 0
                                        begin
                                            --process data here
                                            set @sql = @sqlaction + '|' + @actiontyp + '|' + @store + '|' + @a + '|' + @b  
                                            set @sql1 = '"'+'D:\file.'+@sqleffdate+'.9999999.'+REPLICATE ('0', 3-LEN(@store)) +  @store +'.deltaloc' + '"'
                                            select @sql1 
                                            declare @s varchar(max)
                                            set @s = ''''+'bcp "select ''''' +  @sql + '''''"' + ' queryout ' + @sql1+ ' -c -t "|" -T'+''''
                                            select @s
                                            execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @s 

                                    fetch next from @c into @store
                                        end
                            close @c
                            deallocate @c

                    end


        end
```

Comment: at what line you are getting the error?

Comment: And what is the error?????

Comment: it errors when it executes the bcp.  the error is "procedure expects parameter 'command_String' of type 'varchar'".  I do not get why i am getting this since i placed the param to a varchar variable (@s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace declaration of `@s` to `varchar(4000)` or `varchar(8000)` not `varchar(max)`

```
declare @s varchar(4000)
```

[xp_cmdshell (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

> **command_string**
>
> Is the string that contains a command to be passed to the operating
>   system. command_string is varchar(8000) or nvarchar(4000), with no
>   default.

Comment: That actually worked!  i declared it to 2000 and my script worked perfectly!  thank you for your help!